# NOLOCK and Coldfusion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coldfusion

A co-worker informed me the other day that using `NOLOCK` in a `cfquery` is pointless if you do not include the query inside a `cftransaction`. He claims that SQL Server will only recognize `NOLOCK` inside a transaction and thus not having the query within a `cftransaction` makes the `NOLOCK` redundant.

Can someone confirm is this is true or not, because in all the CF shops in which I've worked , `NOLOCK` is used generously, and it is rarely ever inside a `cftransaction`. Am I supposed to think that all those queries in all those shops are not actually respecting the `NOLOCK`?

Comment: Isn't `nolock`just a dirty read? Why would cftransaction be required for that? And `cftransaction` allows for rollback of processing? Doesn't seem like one needs the other.

Comment: Why you're using NOLOCK?

Comment: @ppshein I think that's a different discussion all together :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your co-worker in incorrect, `NOLOCK` is not redundant outside the context `cftransaction`.

If you are using the default setting in SQL Server, every query you execute is wrapped within a transaction whether you have explicitly typed it out or not.  This is called "[autocommit mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)".

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is look at the execution plans on your SQL Server to see if they're honoring the NOLOCK or not. I can confirm (from years of usage) that the NOLOCK is indeed honored. I wouldn't suggest it (check into READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION), but it's definitely honored, with or without a `cftransaction`.

Answer (score 0):

Ben Nadel has a great explanation as well as a couple of reference articles that explains the use of NOLOCK much better then I can.  However you do not have to use NOLOCK inside of a transaction to get the performance gain.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/477-SQL-Server-NOLOCK-ROWLOCK-Directives-To-Improve-Performance.htm

Hope this helps!
John

Comment: I inherited an application that had NOLOCK in use all over the place.  I stripped them out because best I could tell in most cases it was not for possible deadlock issues.  Saw no changes to performance with removing them.  I did though find some cases where they or some other solution was needed for deadlocks.  But I addressed those cases as they came up.